# MySQL Group by value in comma separated column

Tags: mysql

I could use help with the database query I am trying to pull off. I have a table that has a word or phrase, a product id, a language id, and a version id. The version_id is a comma separated column, since the same word can be used in multiple versions and I tried to avoid adding another row with same data except for a different version.

The table currently looks like this
[image]

I am trying to get the COUNT of word per product, version, and language. The problem I am getting is seperating the version_id since it is a comma seperated column. Is there a way to get the count for all words in version 1, and version 2, separately?

I currently have this query, which works, but it does not separate by versions in a comma separated column.

```
SELECT COUNT( translation ) AS translations, fdp.name AS product, fdv.name AS version, fdl.name AS language, fdl.position 
FROM `fdnfortidictionary_dictionary` AS `fdd`  
LEFT JOIN `fdnfortidictionary_product` AS `fdp` ON fdd.product_id = fdp.id  
LEFT JOIN `fdnfortidictionary_version` AS `fdv` ON fdd.version_id = fdv.id  
LEFT JOIN `fdnfortidictionary_language` AS `fdl` ON fdd.language_id = fdl.id WHERE fdp.enable = 1 
  AND fdd.product_id IN (1,2) 
  AND CONCAT( ",", fdd.version_id, "," ) REGEXP ",(1|2|3|4|5)," 
GROUP BY `language`,`version`,`product`,`position` 
ORDER BY fdl.position ASC
```

The Result I am looking for is something like,
[image]

Comment: The best solution is to not use comma-separated values in the first place. Create another table that lists the versions in separate rows.

Comment: @Barmar I have a table that lists versions per product. But wont this lead to redundant data if the same word is in the new version, or is that just not avoidable?

Comment: The other table should just have two columns, a foreign key that points to this table's ID, and the version number. No redundant data.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for reminding me.. should of goes the next step in normalization!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you might have some luck with [FIND_IN_SET()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)
Probably, something like `FIND_IN_SET(fdd.version_id, fdl.version_id) > 0`

Comment: Will `FIND_IN_SET` be able to return the word count for each version?

Comment: Using that, in place of your CONCAT REGEXP join condition, should join the corresponding records.

Comment: That only results in 1 row,